# For Loop function arguments error

Tags: c++, function, for-loop

```
    void Image::setValues(int start_row, int end_row, int start_column, int end_column, Image & source)
{
    int startPosX = start_row;
    int startPosY = start_column;

    for (int row = 0; startPosX < end_row; row++, startPosX++)
        for (int col = 0; startPosY < end_column; col++, startPosY++)
            std::cout << startPosX << "  " << startPosY << std::endl;
}
```

I call this function like

```
imageTest.setValues(0, 32, 0, 32, imageTest2);
```

I would expect the output of 1024 sets of numbers (32*32) instead I get the output as shown below.

[image: Output]

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to initialize `startPosY` at the beginning of the inner loop.

Try this:

```
void Image::setValues(int start_row, int end_row, int start_column, int end_column, Image & source)
{
    int startPosX = start_row;
    int startPosY = start_column;

   for (int row = 0; startPosX < end_row; row++, startPosX++) {
        startPosY = start_column;
        for (int col = 0; startPosY < end_column; col++, startPosY++)
            std::cout << startPosX << "  " << startPosY << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: @MickCAT Thank you, what a silly error, will mark as answer

Answer (score 1):

`startPosX` and `startPosY` aren't doing anything useful there except making the logic more complex and leading you to make mistakes.

It's much simpler and clearer without them:

```
for (int row = start_row; row < end_row; row++)
    for (int col = start_column; col < end_column; col++)
        std::cout << row << "  " << col << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thank you for this they are for something later